# iajc weave particular aspects using aspect path

Tags: ant, aspectj, compile-time-weaving

I have a library(say lib1) which comprises of a couple of aspect classes(say aspect1.java and aspect2.java).
I want to weave only aspect1.java in my service code. 
Is this possible using ant iajc target in compile time weaving ?
I know this is possible in load time weaving by specifying which aspects to weave in aop.xml.

We have aspectpath in iajc as well, but I am not sure how to configure it to accept individual class files rather than a complete jar file.

```
<target name="weave-with-ajc">
    <ht-aj:standard-aj-weave>
        <inpath>
            <path path="${classes.dir}" />
        </inpath>
        <aspectpath>
            <path path="${standard.compile.classpath}" />
            <path path="${bp:[Library]pkg.classpath}" />
        </aspectpath>
    </ht-aj:standard-aj-weave>
</target>
```

I want to weave only a particular aspect and not all the aspects in the library. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

aop.xml support has been added for compile time weaving as well as per https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=124460

Answer (score 0):

Even though the [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38966378/1512875) [enhancement](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=124460) is still not implemented, they've provided a simplistic way to explicitly specify aspects to be woven at compile-time. In my case, I am using spring-aspects to weave in `AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect` to support `@Configurable` annotation, and the problem is that is weaves in *all* aspects found in spring-aspects.jar (`@Transactional` support, JPA exception translator and so on) which is not what I want (at least I want to have control over this). Based on [this](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg11208.html) post, I am using the following solution:

```
<iajc destDir="${module.bin.dir}" showWeaveInfo="true" >
   <inpath>
      <pathelement location="${module.bin.dir}" />
   </inpath>
   <classpath>
      <path refid="module.classpath" />
   </classpath>
   <aspectpath refid="module.classpath" />
   <inxml> <!-- this is the important part -->
      <fileset dir="${module.src.dir}">
         <include name="aop-ctw.xml"/>
      </fileset>
   </inxml>
</iajc>
```

with `aop-ctw.xml` residing inside the source directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aspectj>
   <aspect name="org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect"/>
<!-- Now, I don't want these:
    <aspect name="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect"/>
    <aspect name="org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect"/>
-->
</aspectj>
```

In case `aop-ctw.xml` is not found, `iajc` goes with the standard behavior: all available aspects are woven in.